How to use the variable Noto fonts (downloaded from Google) with LuaLaTeX?
Under Windows, I have installed the full version of TexLive 2024, and I am writing documents using Visual Studio Code with the Latex Workshop extension. The compiler is latexmk(lualatex). I guess I generally have understood how to use fonts in LuaLatex in simple cases. But I fail to use a downloaded .ttf font.
First of all, the font in question is this one: https://fonts.google.com/noto/fonts?query=Mono
It is a sans-monospaced font from the Noto family. The special thing (?) is that it is variable in two axes (weight and width), and in fact I'd like to leverage that feature by decreasing the with of the font.

First try:
I am aware that TexLive already includes nearly every variant of the Noto fonts. But it seems that the included variants are not variable. The following code could be compiled, and a .pdf file was generated, but the value for Width did not have any effect:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans Mono}
\fontspec{Noto Sans Mono}[Width=80]

\begin{document}
This text should be monospaced.
\end{document}

[ Note: The location of the \fontspec ... line (before or after \begin ...) doesn't matter. ]

Second try:
Since the Width option does not effect anything with the standard Noto fonts, I have downloaded the font mentioned above (which is variable), and have put the .ttf file into the same directory as the .tex file (in this case, c:/Daten/000temp/0001/), and have altered the code shown above as follows:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{NotoSansMono-VariableFont_wdth_wght.ttf}[
    Path=C:/Daten/000temp/0001/
]

\begin{document}
  This should be monospace.
\end{document}

Compiling that code failed. The whole log is too long to post here, so I'll try to show only what's important (in my newbie opinion):
...
Package fontspec Info: 
(fontspec)             Font family
(fontspec)             'NotoSansMono-VariableFont_wdth_wght.ttf(0)' created
(fontspec)             for font 'NotoSansMono-VariableFont_wdth_wght.ttf' with
(fontspec)             options [Ligatures=TeX,Path=C:/Daten/000temp/0001/].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[C:/Daten/000temp/0001/NotoSansMono-VariableFont_wdth_wght.ttf]:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[C:/Daten/000temp/0001/NotoSansMono-VariableFont_wdth_wght.ttf]:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;+smcp;"
...
! error:  (file ) (type 2): cannot find file ''
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
...

The first block probably means that the .ttf file / font has been found and parsed correctly. The second block means what it means, but unfortunately, there's no hint in the log file (neither in the part shown nor in other parts) about what the fatal error could be.
Fair enough - the fontspec documentation tells in part II, chapter 2.2:

Fonts selected by filename must include bold and italic variants explicitly, unless a
.fontspec file is supplied for the font family (see Section 2.3).

Ouch. There is neither a bold variant nor an italic variant of the .ttf file I had downloaded. That the first required variant (bold) does not exist is a matter of course, because it's just the weight (="boldness") that we can set by adjusting the weight axis. The second required variant (italic) does not exist either, eventually because the designers decided that italic variants of monospaced fonts are rarely needed.

Third try:
I think that the missing font variants (bold and italic) could very well make the compilation fail. But the second part of the cited sentence should come to rescue. At least as I understand it, we can escape the requirement for bold and italic versions if we have a .fontspec file. So I decided to try that and altered the code as follows:
File mynoto.fontspec (in the same directory as the .tex file):
\defaultfontfeatures[mynoto]
{
  UprightFont = mynoto-regular,
}
\defaultfontfeatures[mynoto-regular]
{
  Path = C:/Daten/000temp/0001/,
  Font = NotoSansMono-VariableFont_wdth_wght.ttf
}

Here I have nearly literally copied the example code from the fontspec documentation, part II, chapter 2.3.
Tex file:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{mynoto}

\begin{document}
  This should be monospace.
\end{document}

Compiling failed as well. The important (hopefully) part from the log file:
...
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache loaded from C:/Users/peter/.texlive2024/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc.
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: Font "mynoto-regular" not found.

c:/Daten/000temp/0001/test3.tex:4: Package fontspec Error: 
(fontspec)                The font "mynoto-regular" cannot be found; this
(fontspec)                may be but usually is not a fontspec bug. Either
(fontspec)                there is a typo in the font name/file, the font is
(fontspec)                not installed (correctly), or there is a bug in
(fontspec)                the underlying font loading engine
(fontspec)                (XeTeX/luaotfload).
...


In summary, nothing I have tried works, and I'm out of ideas. I could imagine that there is a name conflict between the standard Noto packages / fonts and the one I have downloaded. But this is just a guess, and I'm not able to solve the problem.
What am I doing wrong? What do I need to do to use that font / .ttf file with lualatex?

I cannot answer, but: Get a ttf font other than Noto, especially one that is not part of a multi-width or collection font. Something simple. Then see if your setup can find and use that font. If it cannot, then the problem is with the system or setup. But if it can use that font, then it has something to do with Noto.

Thank you very much for your comment. @David Carlisle's answer is correct, but I still have to find out why his code works and mine doesn't.

It should just work directly with texlive 2024, you can also specify a larger wght feature to get bold

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
BoldFont={NotoSansMono-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf},
BoldFeatures={RawFeature={+axis={wght=900}}}
]
{NotoSansMono-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf}
\begin{document}

123456  \textbf{xyz}

Abcijk  \textbf{123}

\end{document}


At first, thank you very much! I've had a hard time with your answer, because your code didn't compile either. I changed things here and there because I thought there was a syntax error or typo, but nothing worked. Then I found the reason: It is the value 900 that it doesn't like! I can reproduce this at any time: 899 works, 900 causes compiler errors. This is totally weird because the weight value range is from 100 to 900. Could you give an explanation for that? In every case, accepted and +1. I'll now investigate which is the key difference between my code and yours.

er no, I unzipped the google font just for this answer and had it in an empty directory just with the above test and randomly picked 900 as a heavy weight and it worked for me, so I posted, that's all I know, sorry:-) @Binarus

Really no reason to be sorry! Without your answer, I would have given up, and your answer is definitely correct. Of course we could expect that 900 would work, because the range is from 100 to 900. Since I have freshly installed TexLive 2024 a few days ago, maybe there's a bug in my installation, but not in yours. But that was only a side note; the real problem was that I had renamed the font file as described in my own answer. Thanks again!

The accepted answer of @David Carlisle has put me on the right track, and I would like to document my mistake for other visitors. Since the original question already is long enough, I'm describing it in the form of an answer instead of adding more text there.
Having said this:
The file name of the font, as downloaded from Google, is NotoSansMono-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf. This is the file name that is used in the code in the accepted answer.
However, I never liked punctuation marks in file names, so the comma in the file name disturbed me. Therefore, silly as I am, I have decided to replace the comma by an underscore. The filename was now NotoSansMono-VariableFont_wdth_wght.ttf.
This was sufficient to make compilation fail. In other words:
If the font file name is NotoSansMono-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf, the following (even more stripped-off) code works without issue:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{NotoSansMono-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf}
\begin{document}
  This should be monospace.
\end{document}

But if the font file name is NotoSansMono-VariableFont_wdth_wght.ttf, the following code makes the compiler throw errors:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{NotoSansMono-VariableFont_wdth_wght.ttf}
\begin{document}
  This should be monospace.
\end{document}

Further investigation showed that the problem is specific to the underscore character. If I replace the comma in the original file name by another character than the underscore, compilation still works without issues. It is specifically that second underscore that breaks things. [ Note: Of course, I didn't test every character, so there may be additional characters that break it. But I'd say at least that most characters work, but the underscore doesn't. ]
So I managed to lose nearly a working day by choosing the one replacement character out of all characters that brakes things.
I really have no clue what's the problem with the underscore. On one hand, the underscore has a special meaning in Latex, so it might be necessary to quote it in such filenames; I have tried that without success. On the other hand, I would be surprised if lualatex would consider typesetting commands in font file names; if I am right with that, the problem would be due to a parser bug.
Since I am interested in this issue, I'll probably post a separate question about it.

Well done! David (as usual) helped, but I think we can all agree that the filename change is weird.
